# Magento Catalog URL rewrites stuck on processing

Tags: url, magento, catalog, indexer

As the title says my Catalog URL rewrites indexer is stuck on processing.

I've tried everything and I just can't find a solution to this. Does anyone know a solid fix for this?

I've tried truncating core_url_rewrite table and deleting the locks but it still sits on processing. When running it through the admin the page just conitnues loading even though it appears to have finished when I so a count of the table.

Forgive me for asking this again but I'm at a total loss and after days hunting for solutions on the www I've come up blank.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the fix by editing 
app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Model/Resource/Eav/Mysql4/Url.php 
and removing the throwException call on line 253.

Found using the info here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/main.php/viewthread/198534/

Comment: Hey, the URL is broken, are you able to update it by any chance?

Comment: Sorry can't find it now...I guess I should have stuck to the rules and not posted a URL all those years ago! ;)

Answer (score 6):

If your putty gets closed from "software caused network disconnection" or similar, run the script with the & at the end of the command to force the script to run in the background on the server instead of via the terminal.

```
 sudo /usr/local/zend/bin/php /var/www/html/magento/shell/indexer.php reindex all &
```

I am learning too....even better - run with the nohup command:

sudo nohup /usr/local/zend/bin/php /var/www/html/magento/shell/indexer.php reindex all &

Comment: Although I have now solved the problem that is a nice little trick to know. Thanks!

Comment: My pleasure, good luck with the project. I hope this trick helps others who are stuck too.

Answer (score 1):

Try executing `php shell/indexer.php reindexall` from a CLI.

Comment: Thanks. Tried it tho. It times out my putty!

Comment: What is the error you receive if any? Sounds like you need to up your php timeout limits perhaps?

Comment: I don't get any errors. (in Putty I get "software caused network disconnection" or similar). Magento I don't get any errors it just sits on processing. I have the db setup on my local dev machine (xampp on win 7) and it runs in under 60 seconds. Which I guess leads me to believe it's some server config problem. But not timeouts if it should be completing in a minute or two?

Comment: I made a mistake it should be reindexall not indexall. If your Putty is closing out on you upon execution then I would have to say that there is something weird with your LAMP/WAMP stack's configuration or hardware and I would look into it further.  You should see this message after execution: `Catalog URL Rewrites index was rebuilt successfully`

Comment: This is weird: It seems to run ok (but never completes in the browser). If i empty the core_url_rewrite table and run it it keeps indexing the exact same amount (15674). But the urls of my later added sites don't work... Any other ideas?

Comment: If your putty gets closed from "software caused network disconnection" or similar, run the script with the & at the end of the command to force the script to run in the background on the server instead of via the terminal.

 sudo /usr/local/zend/bin/php /var/www/html/magento/shell/indexer.php reindex all &

Answer (score 0):

From the magento root directory:

```
sudo ../shell/indexer.php reindex all
```